# I can't figure out this F# error message

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

The error messages generated by the F# compiler are sometimes confusing. For example:

```
open Deedle
let inds = [1;   2;  6;  8; 11; 12]
let vals = [10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]
let siv = Series(inds, vals)
let fbminmax b (s: Series<float, float>) =
    if b then (Seq.min s.Values) else (Seq.max s.Values)
let sgi =
    siv
    |> Series.groupInto (fun i _ -> i % 2 = 0) fbminmax
printfn "%A" <| sgi
// error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
//    'bool -> Series<int,int> -> 'a'    
// but given a
//    'bool -> Series<int,int> -> float'    
// The type 'float' does not match the type 'int'
```

I understand there is an error (the code works fine with `Series<int,int>` replacing `Series<float,float>` in the definition of `fbminmax`). And I understand that a

`'bool -> Series<int,int> -> 'a'`

was expected. But I do not understand why the compiler says that it was given a

`'bool -> Series<int,int> -> float'`

when it was given `fbminmax`, which is a

`'bool -> Series<float,float> -> float'`

Moreover, if the compiler had indeed been given a

`'bool -> Series<int,int> -> float'`

as it claimed it did that should have been Ok with `float` playing the role of `'a`.

Can someone provide some insight on what is going on?

Comment: I am thinking the argument i is an int, and maybe because of groupInto it should be a float. Difficult to tell since I can't compile this.

Comment: Good point about argument i of the lambda, but I think the compiler was referring to `fbminmax` and not to the lambda, which is `int -> 'b -> bool`.

Comment: I don't understand why it's misidentifying the type of `fbminmax`'s argument, but I wonder if Deedle's `Series` type has any implicit conversion operators from `int` to `float` built in? While F# doesn't allow you to pass `int`s to a function expecting `float`s, it *is* built on the CLI, and there may be something happening down at the CLI layer (which I don't fully understand) that's causing the reported types in the error message to be not quite right. I wonder what you'd see if you decompiled your code to IL instructions?

Comment: @rmunn - Good suggestion about the IL instructions. I will try it, but it will take a few days, as I will not have access to my system over the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error messages can indeed be somewhat cryptic. The solution: maket it generic :-)

```
let fbminmax b (s: Series<'T, 'T>) =
    if b then (Seq.min s.Values) else (Seq.max s.Values)
```

The problem in the end is that you specify `fbminmax b (s: Series<float, float>)` but feed a series of `int`s into it.

Comment: I was aware that I was feeding `<float,float>` instead of `<int,int>`. In my question I wrote `the code works fine with Series<int,int>`. Making it generic fixes the problem, and writing `Series<int,int>` would fix it too. My problem was that the error messages did not make sense, not that there was an error, which I introduced on purpose to exemplify the issue.

Comment: yeah, I know. If you change the order it will complain about `siv` as well. My best guess is that piping into the groupInto expects `int` and then fbminmax expects `float` and then these two things get confused. Whatever the explation, the message is not really helpful. But it's also not worth wasting too much time on. General way of fixing these things is by starting annotating and then removing annotations. Also it's usually better to leave the functions as generic as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but what does the compiler say when you experiment with making your ints floats?

from:

```
let inds = [1;   2;  6;  8; 11; 12]
let vals = [10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]
```

to:

```
let inds = [1.0;   2.0;  6.0;  8.0; 11.0; 12.0]
let vals = [10.0; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0; 50.0; 60.0]
```

Comment: In that case the code works fine. I also had to change the constants in the `fbminmax` definition from `int` to `float`.